# how to handle php session with Unity?

Tags: php, mysql, unity-game-engine, pdo

I'm trying to store score of player in mysql database using the `userID`
but no results.

that's what i wrote into php:

```
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['userGameId'];
$score = $_GET["playerscore"];
stm="UPDATE users SET Score = '$score' WHERE userid = $id ";
```

and this is the C# script:

```
public void insertScore(int score_var)
{

    WWW wwwScore = new WWW ("http://localhost/unity/stage/objectif.php?palyerscore="+score);

    Debug.Log ("sent");
}
```

Comment: I think that problem may be in the url. you have `palyerscore` there instead of `playerscore`

Comment: thanks for your comment. but i verified and also the same problem

Comment: Did u run the `stm` query?

Comment: hi dear, thanks but i tried :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change the URL to,

```
WWW wwwScore = new WWW ("http://localhost/unity/stage/objectif.php?playerscore="+score_var);
```

You have a problem with `playerscore` and `score_var` variable.

You are parsing `score_var` into the `insertScore` method but have not used it inside that method.

Then change the stm query to

```
stm="UPDATE users SET Score = ".$score." WHERE userid = ".$id;
```

That's how you concatenate in PHP

Then you can run the sql query. :)

Comment: hi, thanks for your solution it's working in the browser when  i paste the url but not for Unity :/ a few minitus ago, i discovered from few articles that maybe unity don't handle the PHP SESSION or something like that. but anyway thanks for your help :),,, any other method that could help storing data from unity to mysql using php or using any other method?

Comment: You can use a Server for saving data (like combination of PHP and MySQL Database). Refer this link: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores